# Compilation error while comparing iterator to NULL in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator

I wrote a sample code in C++ to check an element in a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<int> myVec;


    myVec.push_back(1);
    myVec.push_back(2);
    myVec.push_back(3);
    myVec.push_back(4);


    vector<int>::iterator it = NULL; // compilation error

    for(it = myVec.begin(); it != NULL; it++)  // compilation error
    {
        if((*it == 3)
        {
            cout << "3 is found\n"; 
            break;
        }
    }

    if(it == NULL) // compilation error
    {
        cout << "3 is not found\n";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

On compiling this code, I am getting compilation error in the following lines I have marked as comments in the code.

I have read that iterators are just wrappers for how the pointers should walk. So , why an iterator cannot be set or compare to NULL ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"..I have read that iterators are just wrappers for how the pointers..."_ A pointer is an Iterator, but an Iterator is not necessarily a pointer.

Comment: So which iterators can be set or compared to NULL ?

Comment: "So which iterators can be set or compared to NULL?"  The ones that are pointers.  And not the ones that are not pointers.

Comment: Is there any container for which the iterator can be set or compared to NULL ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla Only if you designed it so. None guaranteed in the standard library. Why would you not want to compare with `myVec.end()`?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla -- FYI, old Visual C++ compilers (6.0 and below) would have accepted your code.  Why?  Just because, by fate, Visual C++ 6.0 implemented vector iterators as pointers.  So you would not have been aware that technically, your code was broken.  You later on would have known the hard way, by being one of the unfortunate ones who upgraded from VC 6.0 to a later version, and all of a sudden the code refused to compile.  The moral of the story is to treat iterators as iterators -- don't assume they are pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare `it` with `myVec.end()`.  That is the way vector iterators work.

So,

```
vector<int>::iterator it = NULL; // compilation error
for(it = myVec.begin(); it != NULL; it++)  // compilation error
...
if(it == NULL) // compilation error
```

becomes

```
vector<int>::iterator it = myVec.begin();
for (; it != myVec.end(); it++)
...
if (it == myVec.end())
```

or

```
auto it = myVec.begin();
for (; it != myVec.end(); it++)
...
if (it == myVec.end())
```

Comment: Since you're listing possibilities, you should suggest `for (auto item : myVec)` .

Comment: @YSC, he wants to know how to use iterators and he uses the iterator after the loop has finished..

Answer (score 1):

You should compare it with `myVec.end()`, not `NULL`.

Iterator is a class, not a pointer. So it is meaningless to compare it to `NULL`. You can check it here: [iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/)

Comment: I know it. But I want to know the reason behind NOT NULL.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla iterator is a class, not a pointer. so it is meaningless to compare it with `NULL`.

Comment: An interator instance is a value, not a pointer. The fact that iterators are classes has nothing particularly  to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that iterators are just wrappers for how the pointers should walk. So , why an iterator cannot be set or compare to NULL ?

Iterators are not "just wrappers" of pointers. But let's pretend it does. Does it mean it can be compared to `NULL`?

Let's take a step back and think of "just wrapper" of something else, like an `int`:

```
struct WrapperOfInt
{
    int x;
};
```

And then instantiate it:

```
WrapperOfInt w;
```

So can you compare it to an `int`?

```
w == 1;
```

No, you can't. `WrapperOfInt` is not an `int`, period. You can't compare them.

By analogy, even if iterator is wrapper of pointer, it is just not a pointer. You just can't compare it to `NULL`.